# BASE64DecoderStream fails with InputStream.readAllBytes

Tags: java, stream

I have a small snippet which reads the attachments from an IMAP inbox:

```
BodyPart bodyPart = content.getBodyPart(i);
        
if(bodyPart.getFileName() != null){
    logger.info("Retrieving file {} with size: {} MB", bodyPart.getFileName(), bodyPart.getSize()/1024D/1024);
    Object innerContent = bodyPart.getContent();
                    
    switch(innerContent.getClass().getCanonicalName()){
        case "com.sun.mail.util.BASE64DecoderStream":
            BASE64DecoderStream innerContentStream = (BASE64DecoderStream) innerContent;
                            
            final byte[] actualContent = innerContentStream.readAllBytes();
            //final byte[] actualContent = IOUtils.toByteArray(innerContentStream);
                            
            logger.info("Downloaded {} bytes", actualContent.length);
            files.put(bodyPart.getFileName(), actualContent);
            break;

        default: 
            logger.error("Unimplemented content type: {}",innerContent.getClass().getCanonicalName());
                            
    }
```

With `InputStream.readAllBytes()` the filesize is always 8192 bytes (one buffer), whereas Apache's `IOUtils.toByteArray(InputStream)` reads the files correctly.

I actually wonder why this is the case. Did anyone run into this issue as well?

Java versions:

```
openjdk version "11.0.5" 2019-10-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.5+10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.5+10, mixed mode)
```

Comment: `switch(innerContent.getClass().getCanonicalName())` — Why are you using `switch` as a convoluted replacement for `instanceof`?  And why not just use BodyPart’s inherited [getInputStream](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/mail/Part.html#getInputStream--) method?

Comment: Because I missed the `getInputStream()` method, guess I was too focused on the content keyword. I usually use `switch`es when I want a default case to be set. For me, it's easier to read and easier to add another class here. That's why I am not using `instanceof`. The latter is a personal preference though.

Comment: https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mail/issues/408
It might be related.